# Majorana particles statistics

Tags: anyons, majorana-fermions

What is the influence of Hermitian condition ($\psi=\psi^{\dagger}$) of Majorana fermions operators in their statistical behavior?

A Majorana fermion gas must obey the Fermi-Dirac statistics, or their stastistical behavior may be anyonic?

Comment: What is this $\gamma$? Usually it refers to the $\gamma$ matrices but in the Majorana representation they are purely imaginary, $\gamma^\dagger=-\gamma$ so that Majorana equation can be satisfied by a real field, and not hermitian.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Majorana fermions as defined in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion
are really fermions, as its name indicates. So 
Majorana fermion really have Fermi statistics.
It is not proper to say Majorana fermions obey non-abelian statistics, since fermion always obey Fermi statistics
by definition.

The thing that people said to have non-Abelian statistics are defects
(such as vortices's) that carry a zero-energy mode. 
Such a thing is not Majorana fermions. Calling a zero mode as a Majorana fermion
is really confusing.

Comment: Sadly it is not uncommon to call these vortices or domain walls (with zero modes) for majorana fermions. Some people refer to them as majorana bound states, which might be a better name.

Answer (score 3):

Majorana fermions obey non-abelian statistics and it will be anyonic if your Majorana mode is confined to two dimensions. In $3\text{D}$, you still have the possibility of non-abelian statistics but it is no longer anyonic as the braid group is trivial.

Here are some useful references:

- Majorana Fermions and Non-Abelian Statistics in Three Dimensions, J. C. Y. Teo and C. L. Kane, Phys. Rev. Lett. 104, 046401 (2010). [[1](http://prl.aps.org/abstract/PRL/v104/i4/e046401)]
- Majorana Returns, F. Wilczek, Nature Physics 5, 614 (2009) [[2](http://www.nature.com/nphys/journal/v5/n9/full/nphys1380.html)]
  , and references there in. This article can be downloaded also from Wilczek's webpage.

Comment: The first reference is behind a pay wall. In the future, please include link to arXiv abstract page when possible, e.g., http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4741